# Wolfram Mathematica 11 and MS SQLServer 2019

Tags: sql

I'm trying to connect with Wolfram Mathematica 11 to Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)(Build 19042: ).
I'm unable to do it, and I don't find the documentation for that task.
I tried with

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", 
   "LAPTOP-KD47DDMN:1433/AdventureWorks2019"], "Username" -> "sa", 
  "Password" -> "password"]
```

getting `JDBC::error: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect  $Failed`

I have also created a System ODBC Source (that works). So I tried

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["ODBC(DSN)", "AdventureWorks2019"]]
```

getting `JDBC::classnotfound: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver $Failed`

Any help?

Thanks

Teodoro Marinucci

Comment: Make sure that SQL Server is configured to allow TCP connections. I believe Wolfram Language connects over TCP.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You should test to see if you can connect to SQL server through SQL Server studio management. Then, if still having connectivity issues, use C# or some other client to connect to it. If that works, make sure you have correct parameters that mathematica needs

Comment: Thanks! Now it works!